# Microsoft Graph API : unsupported_response_type

Tags: request, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to authenticate an application on Microsoft Graph API by following this guide : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds/

When i request the permissions from a directory admin, i have got this error :

> error=unsupported_response_type error_description=AADSTS70005: The
>   token request contains one or more unsupported response token type(s):
>   'UnknownTokenType'

I used several URL and URL example, the error is the same : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions

What is wrong with my request?

Comment: I get the same error. Same code worked last week...

Comment: Yes, it worked last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That stopped working for me as well. Found an alternative url to provide admin consent.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxx&prompt=admin_consent&state=12345&redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp/permissions&response_type=code+id_token&nonce=AnyValueShouldBeRandom

This is the standard OAuth consent login but with the addition of prompt=admin_consent.